# Problemas com metodo prepareForSegue passando dados

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple

Eu estou com um problema caras, sou novo no swift, e tenho uma method que pega um resultado de um JSON e eu queria armazena-lo numa variavel local e depois passar essa variavel para uma viewcontroller por segue, porém a variavel quando passo no method prepareForSegue ela pega a variavel como nula ou quando eu iniciei ela:

Pra explicar melhor

1 - instanciei uma variavel no inicio da minha classe da view "A"

```
var id = ""
```

2 - Fiz o NSURLSession e peguei o json de um rest por post e  coloquei dentro do dispatch pra armazenar na variavel que instanciei.

```
func postQueEstouFazendo(v1: NSString, v2: NSString, v3: NSString)
{
    //url para aonde vou mandar o post
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://minhapiqueestoupegando");   

    //inicia a variavel que vai fazer o request
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

    //define o metodo do request
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string

    //coloca os dados em uma string de dados com um titulo
    let postString = "variavel=\(v1)&variavel2=\(v2)&variavel3=\(v3)";

    //define o encoding do que vai ser passado
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    //inicia o envio dos dados
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in           

        //se o erro de envio existir mostra um print
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error ao fazer o recolhimento =\(error)")

            return
        }           

        //aqui é a resposta do envio
        // You can print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

        //aqui é uma outra forma mais completa de visualizar o retorno do envio
        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //teste
        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        do
        {
            let myJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = myJSON
            {
                // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                let idretorno = parseJSON["retorno"] as? String

                //faz a chamada da view voltando para a main thread!
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                      self. id = idretorno!
                })
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    task.resume() // fim do envio e volta pra thread principal ja que a task é uma background thread
}
```

3 - Fiz o metodo prepareForSegue e dentor dele instanciei a destination e coloquei o valor da variavel instanciada na view A para a variavel que eu quero passar para view B

```
//Segues
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
  return true
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){       
        if segue.identifier == "meuidentifier"
        {
          var viewA: viewB = segue.destinationViewController as! viewB
          viewA.idb = self.id
          viewA.outravariavel= 0
        }
    }
```

ESSA LINHA: `viewA.idb = self.id`

quando ta nesse metodo prepareForSegue ele não vai oq eu to pegando la no JSON ele vai "" como  quando eu instanciar.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

No trecho abaixo:

```
if let parseJSON = myJSON
{
  // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
  let idretorno = parseJSON["retorno"] as? String

  //faz a chamada da view voltando para a main thread!
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self. id = idretorno!
  })
}
```

Tente atribuir o valor da variável id antes do dispatch, e verifique com o Debug se a variável está sendo preenchida.

Answer (score 0):

O segue deve estar acontecendo antes de o request voltar. Tenta chamar o `performSegueWithIdentifier` dentro do bloco do request, depois do `self.id = idretorno`.